# How to tile selected columns in an excel sheet into one big column, only selected

Tags: excel, excel-2010, visual-studio-macros, vba

This question is in accordance to the following question:

[Visual Basic move all other columns to create one long column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856000/visual-basic-move-all-other-columns-to-create-one-long-column-b)

I used the best answer:

```
sub ss()
    Dim col As Range

    For Each col In Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns
        If (col.Column > 1 And col.Column < 171) Then
            Range(col.Rows(1), col.Rows(15)).Select
            Selection.Cut
            'Select cell at bottom of A
            ActiveSheet.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste   'Paste
        End If
    Next col
End Sub
```

Now this works, but it tiles all of the columns in the excel sheet to one single column. What I want to do is do it only for the selected columns when running the macro not for the whole sheet.

Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim col As Range
    For Each col In Selection.Columns
        If col.Column > 1 And col.Column < 171 Then
            Range(col.Rows(1), col.Rows(15)).Select
            Selection.Cut
            ActiveSheet.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next col
End Sub
```